# is it possible to get bytes from file of the program that is running?

Tags: c#, file, security, sockets, byte

I'm looking to secure my application from modification and what I was thinking of doing is sending all the bytes of the program to the socket server and the socket server will compute a hash and compare the hash to ensure no modifications have been made to the program before continuing the with session but I want to get the bytes of the program that is running and I was curious if that was possible?

Comment: I believe you can open a file for "read only" multiple times, although it may depend on the OS. Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes works fine. :) Got it to work.

Comment: Side note: byte on the disk have not much to do with code that is running as code can be easily patched after loading from disk...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - can you explain how that would come about? I am assuming protected memory; so how can two identical disk images result in a different program running in memory???

Comment: @Floris - attach debugger at start up (plenty of instructions like - http://bugslasher.net/2011/03/26/how-to-debug-a-process-as-soon-as-it-starts-with-windbg-or-visual-studio-2010/ ), perform patching, continue. Don't forget to always assume that user can get box admin privileges (which if often needed to patch memory of running program).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I see what you are saying. I guess I interpreted the question differently: "make sure that the disk image was not tampered with, from within the program that is running". In other words, I was assuming the person currently logged in was not the malicious agent. I agree in that scenario all bets are off.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating client binaries in client/server handshake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456658/validating-client-binaries-in-client-server-handshake)

Comment: Consider simply signing the file. There is an API call you can make to [verify the signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746313/c-verify-code-signatures-windows-api).

Comment: It's harder than you think.

A determined hacker will modify your object code to compute the hash of the original EXE.

One tenet of securing an application is to work under the premise that the hacker already has your source code. Or to assume that modifying already compiled object code is easy for him.

Answer (score 0):

Simple C demonstration program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  FILE* file;
  unsigned int checkSum = 0, byteCount = 0;
  file = fopen("me", "rb"); // executable called 'me', read binary mody
  if(file != NULL) {
    while(!feof(file)) {
      checkSum = checkSum + fgetc(file);
      byteCount++;
    }
    printf("read %d bytes; ", byteCount);
    printf("checksum computed: %d\n", checkSum);
  }
  else printf("cannot open file 'me'\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Obviously this is not the "right way" to compute a checksum but it shows that an executable that is being run can open itself and read the byte code. After that it's up to you...